# How to use a custom installed font?

Tags: html, css

I downloaded a few fonts from the following website(https://www.fontspace.com/category/tech) to use in my own project, however I'm not sure how to use the fonts in vsCode

I've done the following in an attempt

css file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(a-Astro-Space.ttf);
}

  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

a-Astro-Space.ttf is the name of the file, however I installed it using the typical font installer

html file

```
<header>
<div>
    Geoff's Computer Service
</div>
</header>
```

When I do this, the header is set to the default font and nothing changes

Comment: Re edit: Your code is HTML and CSS. You are writing a webpage. You are not trying to change the font that your code editor shows you code in when you are editing it. VS Code is completely irrelevant to your problem. Take it out of the title and the rest of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> a-Astro-Space.ttf is the name of the file, however I installed it using the typical font installer

The `src` for `@font-face` needs to be the URL to the font file. If you want to use `@font-face`, then it doesn't matter if the font is installed on the end user's system or not.

(Note that font loading is subject to the Same Origin Policy so you'll need to load the website over HTTP and not from a `file:` scheme URL).

If you want to depend on the font being installed on the end user's system, then **don't** use `@font-face`, *just* use the font name (as it is installed under on the end user's system, not the file name) in `font-family`.

---

> ```
>   font-family: myFirstFont;
> }
> ```

You're missing the selector here.

Answer (score 1):

Save your fonts to a folder, for example "fonts".I have saved my fonts as `astro-space.ttf` into my new folder called "fonts"

In your css write the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myFirstFont';
    src: url('fonts/astro-space.ttf') ;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'myFirstFont';
}
```

Make sure that your `src` path is correct and dont forget to put "" into the `url()` so it looks like this `src: url("yourFile");`